# How can I develop a custom Viewer Extension that extends from the viewer SDK's ModelStructurePanel?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I´m trying to develop a custom extension that enhances the filtering/browsing capabilities of the default Model Browser extension. I have followed this tutorial:

https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/dashboard/

I was able to incorporate all the Logger, Summary, Histogram, and DataGrid extensions and customize them to fit the format of model I am currently using (.nwd, in this case); however, I am now trying to develop a more specific extension, and I would like to reuse a lot of the functionalities already provided by the ModelStructurePanel, but I am having a difficult time finding documentation or any information on the topic, and understanding how to implement some of the other SDK classes used for extension development (the SearchBox.js, for example).

I currently have both the extension "skeleton" and the custom panel class I would like to customize, but I am currently stuck because I couldn't find information on how to properly override the methods of the parent class, or if and how I would be able to add more graphical elements into the panel (such as drop-downs with the properties I would like to filter the model's leaf nodes by), while maintaining all of the elements provided by the ModelStructurePanel and their functionality.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find this blog on how to build a custom tree view: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/custom-tree-views

Also, on dropdowns inside panels, we have the [phasing extension](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/phasing-sample-0) that implements that.

Here's its source code: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/blob/main/public/extensions/PhasingExtension/contents/main.js